# How to specify the attribute of document as uri in marklogic using rest api

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

I am trying to insert multiple documents into the `MarkLogic` database using `Rest-API`. I wanted to customize the `uri` while inserting by specifying particular attribute as uri. Here is the json file:

```
{
    "id" : "101",
    "firstName" : "I",
    "middle name" : "Love",
    "last name : "Myself",
    "emailId" : "aaa@gmail.com" 
}
```

If I wanted to specify **emailId** attribute of `json` mentioned above as `uri` while inserting the record. 
Can anybody let me now, How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've initialized a REST API server instance, you [specify document URI using the PUT command](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_16025):

> $ curl --anyauth --user user:password -X PUT -d@'./one.xml' \
>       -H "Content-type: application/xml" \
>       'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/documents?uri=/xml/one.xml'

Comment: hi @wst how to get his done for multiple files in a folder? Meaning if I have 10 json files inside a folder and If i just specify the folder name using `-d@'./folderName'`, how to generate the uri's on the fly(dynamically)?

Comment: The REST API support POST requests with a multipart/mixed payload for bulk writes.  The Content-Disposition header for each document specifies the URI.  See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_54649 and note that the Java Client API and Node.js API provide interfaces that build multipart requests for you.

Comment: @DMA, any REST API is usually accessed programmatically.  curl is a program that can access a REST API for very simple use cases.  For the use case you're presenting I think you'd use a more capable language, like sh or Java.  Or if you're just looking for a simple solution and you don't need to use REST, take a look at mlcp. https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp

Comment: I have asked how to specify one of the attribute of json/XML as uri, while inserting multiple document in folder.

Comment: @RCS, I believe the answer to your question is you write some code in your favorite programming language which can talk HTTP or REST.  Or, if you're just looking for a simple solution and you don't need to use REST, take a look at mlcp.  https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp

Comment: Thanks Sam for the reply. I have created one custom transform function and used it with mlcp which does the job for me.